# Is there a platform-independent way to run Perl/Python/Ruby scripts in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

See title. Currently, I do **either** run the scripts on Windows with a CMD **or** by using a shell on Linux. This seems a bit unflexible to me since it limits the jobs to be run **either** on Windows **or** on Linux.

How would I define a job which simply does run my test scripts written in Perl/Python/Ruby/WhateverOtherScriptingLanguage regardless on which OS the Jenkins instance is running.

The correct script interpreter can be assumed as installed, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cross-platform shell](https://plugins.jenkins.io/xshell/) plugin solves exactly this problem -- however, the last release was done in 2014, and there's a couple of open issues that might prevent you from using it in a production environment.

As an alternative, there is plugins for wrapping the actual call to the interpreter into plugin code. With a plugin, you become independent from OS-specific shells. However, the plugin will be language-specific, e.g.,

- For Python, the [ShiningPanda plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin)  is popular
- For Ruby, the [Ruby plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ruby+Plugin) will do that (albeit only for embedded scripts)
- For Perl, there is no such thing

In any case, you'd depend on availability and maintenance of an additional plugin. Plus, adding fat plugins to Jenkins just to wrap a system call is somewhat awkward.

I reckon that **the most versatile and compact solution** is to introduce a **Groovy build step**, and to start the interpreter with a one-liner from there, e.g.:

```
"perl myscript.pl".execute();
```

This will work on any platform, as long as you ensure that Groovy is available, e.g. by using the  [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin).

If you prefer Python, you can probably do the same with short wrapper that you start via the [ShiningPanda plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ShiningPanda+Plugin).

Answer (score -1):

Shell scripts in Jenkins provide crossplatform she-bang.

```
#!perl
print "hi"
```

will work both on linux and windows, perl should be in PATH.

UPD. Actually we had shell installed on windows hosts so it might be not working without it.